# How to pass list to other activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

How to pass list like `List <Question> quesList` to other activity in Android.

Question is a class like

```
public class Question 
{
        private int Question_id;
        private String Question;        
        private String OPTA;
        private String OPTB;
        private String OPTC;
        private String OPTD;
        private String Answer;
        private int Category_id;
        private String YourAnswer;




//getter and setter methods
}
```

Comment: let the `Question` class implement `Parcelable` and pass the list of questions to another Activity through `Intent`...

Comment: also you can use `public static ArrayList<Question> arr = new ArrayList<Question>();`

Comment: can u please tell the procedure @GopalRao

Comment: @NayaniVikesh You got a good answer from Gaskoin...

Comment: Check my answer.. If it helps you then accept that..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by **Parcelable** and **Serializable**

There are a few steps to achieve it using Serializable .

**Step1:** Create you class and implement Serializable interface. Without implement Serializable interface it is not possible with these steps.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

}
```

**Step2:** Apply this code in your first activity when you are going to **startActivity(intent);**

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MainActivity.MyClass>();
list.add(new MyClass());
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("MyClassList", list);
```

**Step3:** Apply this code in your second activity, you will get arrayList.

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list1 = (ArrayList<MyClass>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClassList");
System.out.println(list1);
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 2):

Your Question should implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface and then you can put your data via intent and its [putParcelableArrayListExtra method][2]

```
Intent intentToLaunchMyNewActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class)
    .putParcelableArrayListExtra("myList", myList);

startActivity(intentToLaunchMyNewActivity );
```

[2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: How to use "mylist" in another activity to display in listview @Gaskoin

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement parcelable interface to your question class :

**note** : i created this template from online tool. you can try it also . go here **http://parcelabler.com/**

```
public class Question implements Parcelable {
    private int Question_id;
    private String Question;        
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String OPTD;
    private String Answer;
    private int Category_id;
    private String YourAnswer;

 //getter and setter methods

protected Question(Parcel in) {
    Question_id = in.readInt();
    Question = in.readString();
    OPTA = in.readString();
    OPTB = in.readString();
    OPTC = in.readString();
    OPTD = in.readString();
    Answer = in.readString();
    Category_id = in.readInt();
    YourAnswer = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(Question_id);
    dest.writeString(Question);
    dest.writeString(OPTA);
    dest.writeString(OPTB);
    dest.writeString(OPTC);
    dest.writeString(OPTD);
    dest.writeString(Answer);
    dest.writeInt(Category_id);
    dest.writeString(YourAnswer);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Question> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Question>() {
    @Override
    public Question createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Question(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Question[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Question[size];
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use that example

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();



serverIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),add_costomer_meter_info.class);
    serverIntent.putExtra("list", list);
      startActivity(serverIntent);
```

and in add_costomer_meter_info.java

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>(); 




Intent intent=getIntent();
 list= (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("list");
```